# UpdateProgress div positioning

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm trying to show a div on top of my grid view when the grid is loading.

This is how I placed my UpdateProgress, UpdatePanel and GridView:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdtPnlRefList" >
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                <span style="border-width: 0px; position: fixed; padding: 50px; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 36px; left: 40%; top: 40%;">Loading ...</span>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdtPnlRefList" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView>
                       ......
                </asp:GridView>
               ...
```

I've used the ProgressTemplate code from another question which I've lost track to, however this code greys out the whole page, but i need to only grey out my grid.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this in the past by using the [Ajax Control Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/get-started-with-the-ajax-control-toolkit-cs)'s UpdatePanelAnimationExtender control.

```
<ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="UpdatePanelAnimationExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="YourUpdatePanel">
<Animations>
    <OnUpdating>
        <Sequence>
            <ScriptAction Script="UpdatePanel_OnUpdating(updatePanelClientID, divToOverlayClientID);" />
            <Parallel duration="0">
                <FadeOut minimumOpacity=".5" />
            </Parallel>
        </Sequence>
    </OnUpdating>
    <OnUpdated>
        <Sequence>
            <Parallel duration="0" >
                <FadeIn minimumOpacity=".5" />
                <ScriptAction Script="UpdatePanel_OnUpdated(divToOverlayClientID);" />
            </Parallel>
        </Sequence>
    </OnUpdated>
</Animations>
```

Ensure that you set the two required ClientIDs on load, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var updatePanelClientID = '<%=YourUpdatePanel.ClientID %>';
var divToOverlayClientID = '<%=divUpdateProgress.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

My div comprises this:

```
<div id="divUpdateProgress" runat="server" align="center" style="display: none; height: 40px; width: 200px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
<asp:Image ID="imgProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/common/waitspin.gif" />
</div>
```

The final piece of the puzzle is the pair of JS functions called by the UpdatePanelAnimationExtender. They look like this:

```
function UpdatePanel_OnUpdating(updatePanelClientID, divClientID) {
// Displays a div over an updating UpdatePanel 
// Get the update progress div 
var divUpdateProgress = $get(divClientID);
// Make it visible 
divUpdateProgress.style.display = '';
// Get the UpdatePanel element 
var pnlUpdatePanel = $get(updatePanelClientID);
// Get the bounds of both the UpdatePanel and the progress div 
var pnlUpdatePanelBounds = Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(pnlUpdatePanel);
var divUpdateProgressBounds = Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(divUpdateProgress);
// Work out where to position the element (the centre of the UpdatePanel) 
var x = pnlUpdatePanelBounds.x + Math.round(pnlUpdatePanelBounds.width / 2) - Math.round(divUpdateProgressBounds.width / 2);
var y = pnlUpdatePanelBounds.y + Math.round(pnlUpdatePanelBounds.height / 2) - Math.round(divUpdateProgressBounds.height / 2);
// Set the progress element to this position 
Sys.UI.DomElement.setLocation(divUpdateProgress, x, y);
}

function UpdatePanel_OnUpdated(divClientID) {
// Related to UpdatePanel_OnUpdating, above. Hides the div once the UpdatePanel has been updated
$get(divClientID).style.display = 'none';
}
```

This code was originally written almost 10 years ago, but I've just successfully reused it in a legacy project.

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:GridView>
    <div style="position: relative;">

        Code goes here

        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdtPnlRefList" >
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="position: absolute; display: table; width: 100%; text-align: center; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);">
                    <span style="border-width: 0px; padding: 50px; font-size: 36px; display: table-cell"; vertical-align: middle;>Loading ...</span>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </div>
</asp:GridView>
```

place the `<ProgressTemplate></ProgressTemplate>` inside the `<asp:GridView></asp:GridView>` tags.
and give the `<div>` a `position: relative;` and the `div` inside the `<ProgressTemplate></ProgressTemplate>` a `position: absolute;`
.

Don't use `opacity` as it applies for the whole tag and everything inside. Unless that's exactly what you want.
I have used an `rgba(255,255,255,0.7);` which will only decrease the opacity of the background color to 70%.

I have vertically centered the `<span>Loading ...</span>` by adding `display: table-cell"; vertical-align: middle;` and adding `display: table;` to the parent tag.

It would be advisable to use a separate stylesheet for all this. =)

Hopefully this helps.

Its a wonderful day to `CODE` =)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this doesn't work as it shows the error "Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not have a public property named 'div'."

Comment: i did update the code a bit. Did included the `<asp:UpdateProgress>` tag?

Comment: Yes i tried that, but the problem is that GridView control doesn't allow adding these controls within it. If you've tested that and it worked, please tell me.